# CSS Every Third of type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given the following markup, how do I select every third 'location-block' in CSS? Thank you! I tried `.location-block:nth-child(3n){}` but that did not work.

```
<div class="location-block">
Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
 Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block"> <!-- Want to Select This -->
 Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
 Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
 Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block"> <!-- Want to Select This -->
 Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.location-block:nth-child(3n) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.location-block:nth-child(3n){ }` works. You can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8u32a7n/)

Also you can use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

```
.location-block:nth-of-type(3n) { 
}
```

Here you have a working example https://jsfiddle.net/8eh2r06h/

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me. Maybe you're using IE 8 or earlier. And, as [drosam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4922156/drosam) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35754266/5095300), maybe use `:nth-of type()` instead, if the `div`s aren't the only children in whatever container they are in.

```css
.location-block:nth-child(3n){color:red}
.location-block:nth-of-type(3n){background:yellow}
```

```html
<div class="location-block">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div class="location-block">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there if you know  your markup(HTML) is going to be all **div's** you don't need the use of clases.

```css
div:nth-of-type(3n){background:tomato}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor
</div>
```

Thanks T04435.